# Image loads as base64 string when send via http/1.0?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to implement http/1.0 in a project with a website that's loaded with a serversocket i've coded. It works fine with character based files. But with image files that i've specified to return the base64 encoded version of the image doesn't work even though the right headers are set such as `content-type: image/png` and `content-transfer-encoding: base64` [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045). I've tried to look at the packets from chrome's networking tool and it looks like it's treating it as a document event though it's an image file. I have no clue whatsoever to do since i've been stuck on this issue for a couple of DAYS! I've searched all of stackoverflow, all of google and i am basically stuck.
I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117548/loading-image-over-http-1-0) question a day or 2 ago where it was recommended to use a byte reader (which i've also tried) without luck. Any visual inputs are of great appreciation.

I have 2 methods that are relevant.

The first one is the one where i choose the way to read the file depending on if it's an image or text.

```
public String readUri(String reqUri) {
    returnFile = "";
    if (this.fileExists(reqUri)) {
        fileType = this.fileType(reqUri); // returns e.g image from image/png
        
        if (fileType.equals("text")) {
            // bufferedreader ...

        } else if (fileType.equals("image")) {
            

             File imgPath = new File(reqUri);
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(imgPath);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)imgPath.length()];
                    fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                    returnFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
                    fileInputStreamReader.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        }

    }

    return returnFile;
}
```

The second one collects this data from the above method. This method is called in my get request controller and sends back the data to the client through the serversocket.

```
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

public String response(
    String HTTPVersion, int statusCode, String fileContent, String contentType) {

    response.append(
            HTTPVersion + " " + 
            statusCode  + " " + 
            this.getHTTPStatusText(statusCode) + "\n"
    );
    
    response.append("Content-transfer-encoding: BASE64");
    response.append("Content-Type: " + contentType + "\n");
    response.append("content-length: " + fileContent.length() + "\n");
    response.append("Date: " + date() + "\n");
    
    response.append("\n");
    response.append(fileContent + "\n");
    return response.toString();
}
```

Here is a request/response from chromes networking tool:
[image: Image here]

This is how the image is currently loaded with the base64 encoding:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand the question. What is the error? Where are you seeing something that you do not expect? Method 1 returns base64-encoded data, right? And method 2 returns a string, right? Do they not work as expected?

Comment: @tucuxi the first method returns the base64 encoded version of the image (i think - haven't seen the image yet). And the second method bundles the different headers and sends it all to the client (a browser). This browser (Chrome) then renderes the image as a string and treats it as a document even though the content-type is set to image/png

Comment: Can you show the exchange, from chrome's network tab point of view? Is chrome performing an HTTP/1.0 GET, or is this delivered via websocket? These details matter a lot to how chrome will receive whatever is being sent

Comment: So chrome is actually performing a HTTP/1.1 GET /someimage.png and then i'm responding with a HTTP/1.0 200 OK, headers and content

Comment: @tucuxi i've added an image of the req/res in the question

Answer (score 3):

**HTTP IS NOT MIME**

RFC 2045 is MIME, and although HTTP is similar in some respects to MIME, it is not MIME, and it differs in other respects. In particular it **DOES NOT USE** `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. It DOES USE `Content-Encoding` with a similar meaning. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.3 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#appendix-C.3 et seq.

Also, you are terminating the lines of the response header with only Java `\n` which is LF. The standards call for CR LF (Java `\r\n`) and always have. *Some* receivers are tolerant, following Postel's dictum, but you shouldn't rely on that. And worse your code doesn't appear to terminate the CTE line *at all*, although since Chrome parsed it okay I'm guessing you just posted the wrong code. Also you should NOT add a line terminator after the body that isn't counted in Content-Length, although if you are using original HTTP/1.0, i.e. without keepalive, this won't matter, because there can't be another request and response on the same transport connection.